# Casio XJ-F10X Projector HDMI port #1

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, lenovo-laptop, google-chrome-os, projector

We have some Casio XJ-F10X projectors and Lenovo Chromebooks (3rd Gen 11e chromebooks/Yoga chromebooks) and found out that HDMI port 1 does not work with the chromebooks (not detected/auto set), while port 2 works as expected.

I called Casio and they suggested testing with another computer, so I used my desktop (Lenovo), and tried 2 projectors, both worked on all HDMI ports. Casio says that both HDMI ports are identical and that it is the Chromebook.

I called Lenovo, did the troubleshooting again, and they say it is Casio's problem.

Whose problem is it?
Why doesn't HDMI port one work with the chromebook?

Comment: Apparently, other Lenovo Cromebooks work on/off with these projectors. This leads me to believe it is a ChromeOS/Lenovo issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Casio had made a revision to this projector model, which fixes this issue. There is no way to tell them apart except for the serial number, and Casio has to look them up to see.